# Byte arrays as standard input / output for external program.

Tags: java, process, stream, arrays, nio

I have an input byte array which I would like to feed to the standard input of an external program (`Process`). Also, I would like to collect the output in a byte array.

What is the most elegant way to do this? `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream`? `nio.channels.Pipe`?

Sample code would be a plus because I can't really figure out how to do this in a good way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `PipedInputStream` with `PipedOutputStream` and Peter's `MultiOutputStream` from another post here, you can get the following:

```
final int CAPCITY = 4096;
final int PIPE_SIZE = 4096;

PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(CAPACITY);
MultiOutputStream multiOs= new MultiOutputStream(pout, bout);

PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream(pout, PIPE_SIZE);
```

Now, if you execute:

```
byte[] bytes = new bytes[1024];
multiOs.write(bytes, 0, 1024);
```

You *feed* your `PipedInputStream`, optionally handing the reference over to another process, i.e. Java Thread. Simultaneoulsy, you write into a byte array, which can be queried by:

```
bytes[] written = bout.toByteArray();
```

Comment: PipedInput/OutputStream are for use *between threads.* If you don't use them between threads you will get deadlocks.

Comment: @EJP As I wrote above: "optionally handing the reference over to another process, i.e. Java Thread". The "optionally" was unlucky. I should have pointed it out, that you should use it in another Thread. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are for use between threads in Java. They aren't part of this solution. To write the byte array to the Process, just call Process.getOutputStream.write(byte[]), as often as necessary. To read it into a byte array, just call Process.getInputStream.read(byte[]). If you don't know how much output there will be, copy it into a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: Right, this is actually what I did when I couldn't get the pipes to work... But since the process runs in parallel with the "main thread" I thought I would be able to get the pipes to work any way. Is this not possible? (There's a fair amount of boiler plate to "manually" loop and transfer the data from the process input stream to the ByteArrayOutputStream.)

Comment: @aioobe no. The reader of a Pipe needs to be in a different thread from the writer of the Pipe. Otherwise using Pipes is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

How about an OutputStream which copies the data. You can attach any number of OutputStreams including ByteArrayOutputStream to this. The first write isn't required except for efficiency.

```
public class MultiOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final OutputStream[] outs;

    public MultiOutputStream(OutputStream... outs) {
        this.outs = outs;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for (OutputStream out : outs) 
            out.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        for (OutputStream out : outs) 
            out.write(b);
    }
}
```